# Vagrant network

Tags: networking, vagrant

I have a vagrant box:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "parallels/centos-7.1"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.hostname = "vagranthost"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
end
```

Guest machine gets ip address 10.211.55.17. Sometimes last number changes, but that doesn't matter.
Host machine is always 10.211.55.**2**.

There is nginx inside the box:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mill.localhost;

    ...
}
```

And simple php script: `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

So, I'm accessing this box from my host machine.

If I access that script from the browser as `http://mill.localhost:8080/`, I'm getting `10.211.55.1`.
I can make `curl -H "Host:mill.localhost" http://10.211.55.17/`, and I'll get excpected result: `10.211.55.2`.

So, the questions are: why is this happening? What is that node 10.211.55.1 in the network? Is there any way, I can get 10.211.55.2 from the browser (http://mill.localhost:8080/)?

Comment: Show the output of `ip a` from all machines.